# Ardupilot and JSBSim do not communicate with each other

Tags: simulation

I’m trying to connect Ardupilot with JSBsim, but something went wrong…
Could someone explain how to fix that? Thanks.

Ardupilot was installed by docs, the same with JSBsim.

Launch command:

```
sim_vehicle.py -v ArduPlane -f jsbsim:Rascal --console --map
```

Console output:

```
Waiting for heartbeat from tcp:127.0.0.1:5760
MAV> link 1 down
```

Linux 20.04 LTS. Latest versions of Ardupilot + JSBsim

It's the same with FlightGear - it seems like it doesn't "see".

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jeEt.png)

I tried reinstalling JSBsim as well as Ardupilot, tried different models, and also looked for a problem in the ports (I can’t determine for sure yet)